# Sample to implement CQRS pattern in asp.net core 2.0 webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, cqrs

I am new to CQRS pattern. I am looking for some working sample to implement CQRS pattern in asp.net core 2.0 webapi.

Can anyone suggest me a proper link for this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

they are many Frameworks on GitHub that will work on .net Core (maybe need to create new Project and copy Paste code for .net Standard Library)
one of the simplest IMHO is https://github.com/edumentab/cqrs-starter-kit :) just take the code in your Core app :)

Comment: While links can be useful, it is recommended to include the contents of the links as the answer will be of no use if the data on links is removed or replaced.

Comment: should i include the whole sourcecode from the linked project in my post? or what do you mean?

Comment: If not complete source code, atleast some code or sudo code which can be helpful. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: sorry but this isnt usefull at all... only the whole project make sense. and he requested "working sample to implement". 

PS: maybe you should also not post links.. instead copy out the text...